# How to run background process/ multithreaded process for the better performance of the app in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

performing the background process for Accessing the address book from the phone and saving into local sqlite3 database. I have done like below.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(syncAddressBookToDB:) withObject:nil];
 - (void)syncAddressBookToDB:(id)sender
{
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

 // accessing the address book and saving to the database.
   GVDBManager *objDB = [GVDBManager getSharedInstance];
   [objDB getContactsFromAddBook];
   [objDB syncPhoneBookWithVcardsTable];

   [pool drain];
}
```

is there any better way to achieve the background/ multithreaded process to improving the performance of my app. Anyone Please suggest me the better solution for this.

Comment: why ? is it not good enough ? you already are doing job on a another thread and if it is working slow then your problem is within running code, not threads', i hope i was clear..

Comment: If you want a bit more control over the threads but not too much complexity, look into GCD here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Grand Central Dispatch is generally a better and more recommended way of handling a task like this vs using the `performSelectorInBackground:` method. You can do it like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t loadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Image loader", NULL);
dispatch_async(loadQueue, ^{
    // Your code to run in the background here
});
```